# magento image loading takes too much time

Tags: image, magento, loading

I have a problem with magento application. the site taking too much time to load. problem is with category page , images of category are not loaded as it should.

can anybody help to find solution.hosting server is bluehost.

everything was working fine previously, but now i am facing these issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than caching the images, there isnt much you can do except maybe upgrading the hosting account. If you are on a shared hosting account and loading 10+ product images on a page, it may take 6-7 seconds to load.

You should check the size of the images. If you are uploading images from your digital camera, a lot of times they can be several megabytes in size.

I would suggest using jpg images no larger than 800px x 800px in size. And make sure Magento cache is enabled. Each full resolution image in file size should be under 250KB.

You could also attach your magento store to a cloud service that caches images and pages which can greatly improve speed.

One more thing you can do, open a ticket with bluehost and ask them to check the speed of the site, lots of times they have tools they can run diagnostics. Maybe its something other than the images slowing things down like javascript getting hung up (any extensions installed related to the images?)